# How to merge attributes from associated models into one nested attribute in serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

Below is my json after rendering '@products'. As you can see, there are 2 other models nested (vendor_products and vendors). The association between product and vendor models is many-to-many with 'vendor_products' being connecting tables. What I wanted to achieve here is - instead of having both 'vendor_products' and 'vendors' models being nested I just want to add 'vendor name' as another attribute inside the vendor_products model.

```
{
   id: 1,
   barcode: 3045320001525,
   name: "xyz",
   size: "370 g",
   brand: "abc",
   img_url: "http://xyx"
   vendor_products: [
      {
        id: 1,
        v_item: "JAM101",
        vendor_id: 1,
        case_price: 72
      },
      {
         id: 2,
         v_item: "1001",
         vendor_id: 2,
         case_price: 65
      }
   ],
   vendors: [
      {
        name: "vendor_xyz"
      },
      {
        name: "vendor_123"
      }
   ]
},
```

Below is the format of json I wanted:

```
{
   id: 1,
   barcode: 3045320001525,
   name: "xyz",
   size: "370 g",
   brand: "abc",
   img_url: "http://xyx"
   vendor_products: [
      {
        id: 1,
        v_item: "JAM101",
        vendor_id: 1,
        vendor_name: "vendor_xyz",
        case_price: 72
      },
      {
         id: 2,
         v_item: "1001",
         vendor_id: 2,
         vendor_name: "vendor_abc",
         case_price: 65
      }
   ],
```

Here are my serializer classes:

```
class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :id, :barcode, :name, :size, :brand, :img_url

 has_many :vendor_products
 has_many :vendors
end

class VendorProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :id, :v_item, :vendor_id, :case_price
 belongs_to :product
 belongs_to :vendor
end

class VendorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :name
 has_many :products
 has_many :vendor_products
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a custom attribute in vendor_products serializer,

```
class VendorProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

 attributes :id, :v_item, :vendor_id, :case_price, :vendor_name
 belongs_to :product
 belongs_to :vendor

 def vendor_name
   object.vendor.name #object is current vendor_product object get name from that
 end
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you! I do need to dig into the custom attribute as I am not quite sure how this is working as I am very new to this concept.

Comment: Check out this guide https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/serializers.md